# How do i get my retrofit to wait until its done before i start my recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to make my recycler view wait until my retrofit function is done. The retrofit function is stored in a view model while the recyler view is in my activity. I can get it to work with a delay but that does not seem like a good way to do it.

```
        GlobalScope.launch {
        suspend {
val txt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textbox)
            viewModel.getStaff()


            delay(10000)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                Log.d("coroutineScope", "#runs on ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                createRV(viewModel.pictureList, viewModel.actorList, viewModel.characterList, viewModel.houseList)

            }
        }.invoke()
```

and this is my retrofit function

```
suspend fun getStaff(){
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
    val service = retrofit.create(HarryPotterApi::class.java)
    val call = service.staff()

    try {

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<Staff> {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Staff>, response: Response<Staff>) {

                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    val characterData = response.body()!!
             

                     pictureList.add(characterData[0].name)
                     actorList.add(characterData[0].name)
                    characterList.add(characterData[0].name)
                    houseList.add(characterData[0].name)
                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Staff>, t: Throwable) {

            }
        })}catch (e: IOException) {

        e.printStackTrace()
    }

}
```

Comment: Retrofit has support for coroutines since `2.6.0`. Just make your `staff()` function suspend and then you can use it synchronously, making your code much simpler.

Comment: Do you mean getStaff (). If so it is but it is grey and says its redundant.

Comment: No, I mean `HarryPotterApi.staff()`. I don't have your full code, but you can make it something like: `suspend fun staff(): Staff` and then use it just like this: `val characterData = service.staff()`. Then you can remove 60% of the code inside `getStaff()` and at the same time you fixes the problem with waiting for the result.

Comment: Ok, I added what I mean in the answer. Just note it may not be a fully working example.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a better way.
Rather than `delay (10000)`, hide the recyclerView and use a placeholder view instead

When you are ready to display the recyclerView:

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {

placeholderView.visibility = View.GONE
recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                Log.d("coroutineScope", "#runs on ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                createRV(viewModel.pictureList, viewModel.actorList, viewModel.characterList, viewModel.houseList)

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit supports coroutines and suspend functions since `2.6.0`, so you don't have to use callbacks and then somehow convert asynchronous  call into suspendable (which is also possible). You can make `HarryPotterApi.staff()` itself suspendable and them make your whole code much simpler and synchronous, at the same time fixing your problem with waiting for `getStaff()` to finish.

I don't have your full code, but I assume `HarryPotterApi.staff()` is declared something like this:

```kotlin
fun staff(): Call<Staff>
```

Make it suspendable:

```kotlin
suspend fun staff(): Staff
```

Then use it synchronously:

```kotlin
suspend fun getStaff(){
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
    val service = retrofit.create(HarryPotterApi::class.java)

    val characterData = service.staff()
    pictureList.add(characterData[0].name)
    actorList.add(characterData[0].name)
    characterList.add(characterData[0].name)
    houseList.add(characterData[0].name)
}
```

It may not be a fully working example, but I hope you get the idea.

Note that unlike your original solution, above `service.staff()` will throw an exception on the request failure (thanks @Tenfour04 for pointing this out). Depending on your needs you could catch it or propagate it to the outer code. Ignoring the failure, as in your original code, doesn't seem like a good solution, because the code that follows `getStaff()` call uses the data that `getStaff()` was supposed to retrieve.

Comment: I've barely used Retrofit, but I think a Retrofit suspend function throws an Exception if it fails to connect or retrieve the response, so it would be worth mentioning that it should be wrapped in try/catch or runCatching, unless that's handled higher up the call stack. It contrasts with `Call.enqueue()`, which does not throw and only calls the `onFailure` part of the callback.

Comment: Good point. I assumed throwing an error is a desired behavior, because the code that follows `getStaff()` uses the retrieved data, so it doesn't make too much sense to continue.  And that the original code consumed the failure only because OP wasn't sure how to convert callbacks to synchronous. But you're right, I shouldn't change the behavior without the explanation. Thanks, updated.  @Tenfour04